# Are there premice that are $\omega_1$-iterable but not $(\omega_1+1)$-iterable?

Tags: set-theory, inner-model-theory

For (hopefully) simplicity, let a premouse be defined coarsely as in Martin and Steel's 1994 paper, *Iteration Trees*.

Is (or is it consistent that) there is a premouse that is $\omega_1$-iterable but not $(\omega_1+1)$-iterable?

Note: if adding some extra conditions will get partial answers, that would also be very helpful.

Comment: (Silly comment: at first I thought for sure "premice" was a typo for "premise"...)

Comment: @SamHopkins If you're doing inner model theory in linear logic, I suppose you could have an iterable premise about iterable premice. :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is consistent (relative to large cardinals). There is an example given in Example 3.6 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.07185). For a brief summary: the model is the minimal proper class mouse $S$ such that $\mathbb{R}^S$ is closed under the $M_1^\#$-operator. In particular, $M_1^\#$ is a proper segment of $S$. And $S$ satisfies "$(M_1,\delta^{M_1})$ is a premouse and $(M_1,\delta^{M_1})$ is $\omega_1$-iterable but not $(\omega_1+1)$-iterable" (with these definitions in the sense of "Iteration trees"). In $S$, there is a tree $\mathcal{T}$ on $M_1$, formed via a variant of self-genericity iteration, which has length $\omega_1$ and no cofinal branch in $S$. (The usual sort of self-genericity iteration would be formed by iterating to make some initial segment of $S$ generic for the $\delta$-generator extender algebra. In the variant used, one also interweaves countable linear iterations at appropriate stages of the process, each of which "moves past the next instance of the $M_1^\#$-operator on the $S$-sequence"; this ensures that $\delta(\mathcal{T})$ is a limit of $M_1^\#$-operator instances on the $S$-sequence, which in turn ensures that $\delta(\mathcal{T})=\mathrm{lh}(\mathcal{T})=\omega_1^S$.)

Comment: Thanks heaps!!!

Comment: A probably-naive follow-up question: do further large cardinals eventually imply that $\omega_1$-iterability implies iterability?

Comment: Farmer S: Can you recommend a good paper to get get more comfortable with self-genericity-iteration? I suppose I'd be looking for a gentle proof that M_1 has proper grounds. I'd like to get a better idea of why the final branch isn't in M_1 (although the common part model suffices).

Comment: @TobyMeadows It is discussed in section 3.1 of "HOD as a core model", in the new Cabal volumes. See in particular 3.16 and 3.20 there. (This is in the numbering of a preprint that I have; I'm not sure whether it matches the numbering in the final version. But in the preprint, 3.16 is labelled "Pseudo-genericity iteration".)

Comment: By the way, one can make do with a simpler model than the $S$ I used above: you can do a similar thing starting with the minimal proper class mouse $S'$ such that $M_1^{\sharp}$ is a proper segment of $S'$ and $\mathbb{R}^{S'}$ is closed under sharps.

Comment: Thanks again. That's very helpful!